# Object index pass number is always 0

Tags: objects

I've implemented a simple script to get pass index of objects in a scene:

```
def list_all_objects():
    for o in bpy.data.objects:
        print(f"Name: {o.name}, index: {o.pass_index}")
    return
```

But all indexes in the output are `0`:

```
Name: Area.000, index: 0
Name: Area.001, index: 0
Name: Area.002, index: 0
Name: Area.003, index: 0
Name: Bottle, index: 0
Name: Camera, index: 0
Name: Floor, index: 0
Name: Sticker, index: 0
Name: Straw, index: 0
```

So that means pass indexes are initialized by `0`. Is there any API to initialize these indexes so that they are distinguished?

Comment: nope, AFAIK you have to do that manually (or by script/add-on)

Comment: Of course they are all 0.  This is the _Pass Index_ value which you find under _Object Properties_ > _Relations_ and it is a **render pass**, similar to the _Pass Index_ in the _Material Properties_. This is no indexing to serially number the objects in the scene. This index is used (if enabled under _View Layer_ > _Passes_) to separate objects in the _Compositor_ by filtering/masking per index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

and since you already wrote that, script, just add a few lines:

```
def set_pass_indices():
    counter = 1
    for o in bpy.data.objects:
        print(f"Name: {o.name}, index: {o.pass_index}")
        o.pass_index = counter
        counter = counter + 1
        print(f"after: Name: {o.name}, index: {o.pass_index}")
    return
```

and you get what you want ;)